Bayesian Mediation Analysis
I have:

1 binary outcome (0, 1)
1 continuous quantitative mediator
1 continuous quantitative predictor

I would like to compute Bayesian mediation analysis with Liu et al. (2023) method. The formula is 

I specify the prior odds value for each of the two path as default value 1 (Liu et al., 2023)
For a path, I have performed a Bayesian linear regression with default JZS beta prior. So I have a BF10 for a path.
For b path, I have performed a Bayesian logistic regression using default CH prior (1, n, 0). So I have a BF10 for b path.

Then simply apply these values in the formula and calculate the BFmed? Is that correct? Or do I need to make modifications because in my case the outcome is binary and therefore BFa and BFb come from two different analyses?
Thanks for your help
